# Display additional information on vertex of a graph

Tags: r, igraph, vertex-attributes, tkplot

I have an oriented graph, using the following example

```
ba <-  sample_pa(n=100, power=1, m=1,  directed=T)
V(ba)$color<-"yellow"
tkplot(ba , layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold(ba), canvas.width=1024,canvas.height=768)
```

I would like to find the way to display additional information when I rightclick on a vertex or having the display of the information using a tooltip that appears when i move the mouse on each of the vertex. I tried to set attributes to the vertex but I can't find the way to display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dunno about `tkplot`, however here's an alternative that displays a tooltip on hovering over the edge. The same works for vertices, too:

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
library(fortunes)
set.seed(1)
ba <-  sample_pa(n=100, power=1, m=1,  directed=T)
V(ba)$color<-"yellow"
E(ba)$title <- sapply(1:ecount(ba), function(x) paste(strwrap(fortune(x)$quote, 40L), collapse="<br>"))
visIgraph(ba) %>% 
  visEdges(color = "black") %>% 
  visIgraphLayout("layout.fruchterman.reingold") %>%
  visOptions(width = "1600", height = "1200")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks luke now I am trying to convert the information to be used by visNetwork, I will let you know soon

Comment: Now I am fighting to understand how to enlarge the size of the display window

Comment: Zoom in/out using your mouse?

Comment: When the graph has been drawn in the web brwoser, it uses just a portion of it, half size of the full page, so I want to increase the space where the graph will be drawn

Comment: You can add `%>% visOptions(width = "1600", height = "1200")` or sth similar.

Comment: Great it worked, can you put please as official answer so i can put it as a good answer?

Comment: sure, just added it